# Copy Excel Worksheet from one Workbook to another with twapi

Tags: excel, tcl

I am trying to combine multiple excel files from one folder one file, copy all sheets from all files to single with below code, But no luck. Can someone help here please....

```
set file1 {D:\Temp\CombineExcel\Work\1240676493.xlsm}
set file2 {D:\Temp\CombineExcel\Work\1735749199.xlsm}

set xl [ ::twapi::comobj Excel.Application ];
set wb [$xl Workbooks];
set wb1 [$wb Open $file1];
set wb2 [$wb Open $file2];
set f1w1s1 [$str_fil1 WorkSheets]
set f2w2s2 [$str_fil2 WorkSheets]
```

Comment: Curious. I'd expect `[$wb1 WorkSheets]` so that it's at least using an existing likely-looking variable… and you don't need to put `;` at the end of the line in Tcl (though it's harmless). Can't really say much else though, not enough to answer properly; I'm on the wrong platform so I can't test anything at all and I don't know TWAPI, COM or Excel's object model well enough.

Comment: all sheets or just one ?

Comment: Hi Mkn, I want to keep that option open (Some times some specific sheets, sometime all)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy the sheet**1** of file**2** in file**1** you can do like this :

```
# Open COm Excel
set excel [twapi::comobj Excel.Application]
$excel DisplayAlerts [expr 0]
set workbooks [$excel Workbooks]

set wb2 [$workbooks Open $file2] ; # Open file2
set wb1 [$workbooks Open $file1] ; # Open file1

# Second file
set ws2 [$wb2 Worksheets]
set worksheetId [$ws2 Item [expr 1]] ; # First sheet of file2
$worksheetId Activate
set range [$worksheetId Cells] ; # select all...
$range Copy

# First file
set ws1 [$wb1 Worksheets]
set lastWsId [$ws1 Item [$ws1 Count]]
set worksheetId [$ws1 -callnamedargs Add After $lastWsId]
$worksheetId Activate

$worksheetId Paste ; # Paste the result in file1 after the last sheet

$wb1 Save ; # Save file1
$excel Quit

# Destroy all objects...
foreach obj [twapi::comobj_instances] {
    $obj -destroy
}
```

If you want copy an specific sheet you can work with the name `[$worksheetId Name]`

Comment: Thanks you for your valuable inputs, it solved 90% of problem, but after copying cell excel messing up with formatting, is there any option to preserve source formatting?

Comment: it's works for me , but i tried with simple example (border , background , font) maybe you may contact with the author...

Comment: Is there a way to copy the worksheet instead of the range? I think that might resolve the issue if yes. I don't know enough of the twapi package to give suggestions :(